# ¿Como abrir una pagina web con un Floating Action Button?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

aun no se como usar los FAB bien, así que, me preguntaba si hay alguna forma de que estos puedan abrir paginas web ¿?

Aquí dejo el código de mi botón:

```
binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Redireccionando hacia https://support.activision.com/es/cod-mobile", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
```

Edit:

parte del codigo donde viene el contexto del boton:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Escribe más del código para ver el contexto de dónde tienes el FloatingActionButton

Answer (score 0):

No termino de entender bien cuál es tu problema, pero si lo que quieres es abrir el una url específica desde el FAB, simplemente creas la url, la parseas y le asignas el evento al botón. Algo así:

```
    binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Redireccionando hacia https://support.activision.com/es/cod-mobile", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();
        url = "laurl.com";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent abrirweb= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(abrirweb);
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es justo lo que nesecitaba.

Comment: No hay porqué, no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta para que se cierre la pregunta :)